# On android AIDE IDE android volly showing error when I try to use getheader() method

Tags: java, android

android volly showing error when I try to use getheader() method.
I was trying to do a simple task which needs some networking with volly I'm using Aide ide on my android tablet. I couldn't figure out how to fix this 
Error

1. method onResponse does't override method from its super class
2. method onErrorResponse does't override method from its super class

//My code

```
private void jsonObjectMethod(){
    String url = "www.example.com"; 
    // enter url here
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // Handle your response
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Handle your error
        }

    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError{ 
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
            params.put("Accept-Language", "en");

            return params;  
        }
    };



    MainApplication.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bV1p.png)

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Here is the screenshot  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bV1p.png

Answer (score 1):

There are some methods you haven't overridden. WHen you extend or implement a class, there are some classes you have to override. With classes you have to override abstract methods, and with interfaces you have to override all methods. So the error is because there are some methods you haven't overridden and in this case you are missing onResponse and onErrorResponse. I'm not sure if it is those two, but it looks like that from the poorly formatted error in your question.

And if you ask a question in the future, don't provide a screenshot. Format it and add it into the question, don't mash it into a single line

Comment: I have edited it.  sorry for the mistakes this was my first question... I think the problem is with the AIDE IDE even sample codes and other  projects show the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with aide. To solve this problem, all you have to is assign these two listener in a variable like below.

```java
Response.Listener resListener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // Handle your response
        }
    };
Response.ErrorListener errListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Handle your error
        }
    };
```

After that use these to listner by calling there references.

```java
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, resListener, errListener) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError{ 
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
            params.put("Accept-Language", "en");

            return params;  
        }
    };
```

It should work.